# Webpack-Dev-Server giving error 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type' for .jsx file

Tags: gruntjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I am using the grunt-webpack. Trying to start the webpack-dev-server gives this error
`Module parse failed: /u/saxenat/react-blueprint/src/js/app.jsx Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Before you close this question, let me just say: webpack is bundling the files properly. The `grunt-webpack` plugin provides 2 tasks: `grunt-webpack` and `grunt-webpack-dev-server`. When I try HMR with the server, it is failing. Otherwise it works fine.

I have included `babel-loader` with presets `es-2015` and `react`.

Any ideas?